# After adding .name I get undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am following a One Month Rails Course on skillshare.com and ran into a problem I haven't been able to fix myself (yet).

I am making a simple app similar to pinterest.  I am at a step where we are trying to get a users name under their picture after they post a picture.  It will say "posted by: (name)."

Here is my code that has the error:

```
<div class="box">
<%= link_to (image_tag pin.image(:medium)), pin %>
<p class="description">
    <%= pin.description %>
</p>
<p>
    <strong>
        Posted by: <%= pin.user.name %>
    </strong>
</p>
<% if current_user == pin.user %>
    <p>
      <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_pin_path(pin) %>
      <%= link_to 'Destroy', pin, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
    </p>
<% end %>
```

In the center between the strong tags, I have "Posted by: <%= pin.user.name %>".  I tried taking out .name and my site will load without the "undefined method 'name"" but I get a bunch of whacky numbers (im guessing this is what ruby or rails defines the user as, and then the name is assigned to that batch of numbers being displayed right now).

My guess is that I need to define .name somewhere, I'm not too sure where to do this or how.  If anyone can look this over I would appreciate. Thanks!

**I just found this code in my show.html.erb file

```
<div class"row">
    <div class="span6 offset3">
        <div class="well">
            <%= image_tag @pin.image %>
            <%= @pin.description %>
            <p>
              <%= @pin.user.name %>
            </p>
            <% if current_user == @pin.user %>
            <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_pin_path(@pin) %> 
            <% end %>|
            <%= link_to 'Back', pins_path %>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

pin.user.name works in this case but I still can't get it to work in the first snippet of code above.

model/user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :confirmable,
  # :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable #recoverable

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :name
  # attr_accessible :title, :body

  has_many :pins, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

Comment: Can you post the code from your User model class?

Comment: In your first snippet above you do `<%= pin.user.name %>` but then in your second snippet you do `<%= @pin.user.name %>` notice the difference ;)

Comment: I just added the model/user.rb above.  @David, yes I see the @ symbol.  I tried running it with the @ symbol in it and it still didn't work.  I know in a section of the video guide they mentioned very briefly that sometimes you use the @ and sometimes you don't.  In the first piece of code above current_user == pin.user works without the @. I am guessing this is a case I don't have to use the @?

Comment: @ScottD'Alessandro What is the first snippet?

Comment: @David The filename is _pin.html.erb  Here is the route code/omrails/app/views/pins/_pin.html.erb

Comment: I may be incorrect by the naming of the file `_pin.html.erb` indicates to me that this is a partial correct?

Comment: Can you try `<%= @pin.user.try(:name) %>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you have some `pin` records, that don't have a `user_id`. You should check this by  using the rails console (`rails c`) with the following statement:

```
Pin.where(:user_id => nil)
```

Add something like `validates :user_id, :presence => true` to your user model to ensure that ever `pin` has a corresponding user.

Comment: This got me to the root of my problem and everything appears to be working.  I remembered in one of the videos (before we even had pictures in the app) the instructor touched on using this command Pin.first.delete .  This was to delete any pins on the board that didn't have a user associated with it.   I ran Pin.first.delete and just deleted everything from my board.  Validating: I have a few validation commands in my pin.rb, do you think I should have them in both?

Comment: Run `Pin.destroy_all(:user_id => nil)` and check whether the error still appears.
You definetely should add the validation I suggested, if you want to do things like `<%= pin.user.name %>`

Answer (score 0):

Okay so we've established that this is supposed to be a partial. Which in this case you need to pass in the `form_for` variable that you are rendering. I maybe incorrect but I believe what you are is as followed. This creates a form and a scope around the model object. So in this case I believe you will have the following:

```
   <%= form_for(@pin) do |f| %>
    <div class="box">
    <%= link_to (image_tag pin.image(:medium)), pin %>
    <p class="description">
        <%= pin.description %>
    </p>
    <p>
        <strong>
            Posted by: <%= pin.user.name %>
        </strong>
        <% end %> 
    </p>
    <% if current_user == pin.user %>
        <p>
          <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_pin_path(pin) %>
          <%= link_to 'Destroy', pin, method: :delete, data: 
                                     { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
        </p>
    <% end %> 
  <% end %>
```

You may benefit from reading [Ruby on Rails Guide - Using Partials](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials)

Comment: Thanks so much, I'm going to look over this code right now.  I think I kinda have it working now in it's current state.  Since this is a guide I am following, my guess is that the form_for may be added in later videos?  I should finish up the guide later tonight and will know then :)

Comment: No worries hopefully it helps

Answer (score 0):

I'm taking this class as well. Having another issue, but reading through the class materials there were some clear steps to rectify:

Troubleshooting Note: You should probably delete any pin that doesn't have a user associated with it, otherwise you'll get a undefined method 'name' for nil:NilClass error when you try to load your pins index page. Follow these steps:

```
$ rails console
>> Pin.destroy_all(user_id: nil)
$ heroku run rails console
>> Pin.destroy_all(user_id: nil)
```